# Photoshop Apply JPEG

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I know that you can save image as JPEG and make it with quality from 0 to 12.

Well, is it possible to make it with exact layer/selected region. I mean add "JPEG" low-quality effect?

Maybe any plug-ins?

Comment: So you want a specific area within an image to be low-quality while the rest of the image is high-quality?

Comment: @AndrewH yeah. That's I want.

Comment: Are you trying to keep everything as one image?

Comment: @AndrewH yeah, why not?

Answer (score 1):

- Divide the image using guides
- Activate the **Slice Tool** > top options > **Slices From Guides**

[image: slices]

[image: Slices II]

- **Menu File** > **Save for Web...** > Choose the JPG quality

[image: Save for web]

- At the save for web window choose: **Image Only** / **All Slices**

[image: All slices]

- Back to the file, get the **Slice Select Tool** and click a slice
- **Menu File** > **Save for Web...** > Choose the JPG low quality
- When saving choose **Image Only** / **Selected Slices**

[image: Selected Slices]

Comment: I'ts not for layer, but for part of image.

Comment: This answer is for a part of a image, there's not any layer

Answer (score 0):

Save a copy of the layer you want as a low-quality image.

If your selection has a transparency mask using a non-destructive process, simply replace the layer with the saved image.

Comment: I know it before, but is there method without saving additional files?